# c# textbox data binding with date format

Tags: c#, textbox, .net-4.0, string-formatting

I have `Textbox` bounded from sql server database

column type is Date. so there is no time in that column

when binding data from database to this `Textbox` it shows date with time it is look like default time or something because it always has same value = `12:00:00`

```
TB_Birthday.Text = dt.Rows[1][5].ToString();
```

First where that date comes from ?
last How do I remove this time and show only date?

I am using .net4 with vs 2013

[image]

Comment: `TB_Birthday.Text = (dt.Rows[1][5] as IFormattable).ToString("M/d/yyyy");` `12:00:00` stands for a midnight `12 A.M` (`0:00:00`)

Comment: The title is misleading. This has nothing to do with textbox data binding...

Comment: @ChristianMurschall the data in textbox is bounded from database

Comment: @DmitryBychenko un but from where time comes of it not exist at source and couln source is `date` not `datetime`

Comment: @sam: You get `DateTime` (which has `Date` part and `Time` part). `Time` part is all zeroes. When formatting `DateTime` to the `string` via `ToString` you use default formatting which includes `Time` part (all zeroes) in a form `12:00:00` (midnight in 12 hour format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dt.Rows[1][5]` returns `object` and we want apply a *format* we have to cast it to `IFormattable` interface:

```
 using System.Globalization;

 ...

 // "M/d/yyyy" - Month / Day / Year in this order; e.g. "9/14/2019"
 TB_Birthday.Text = (dt.Rows[1][5] as IFormattable)
   ?.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I've put `?.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()` in order not throwing exception if `dt.Rows[1][5]` is `null` but *propagte* null to `TB_Birthday.Text`: `TB_Birthday.Text` will have an empty `Text`. In case of *.net 4.0 vs 2013* (see comments below) we have to put

```
 TB_Birthday.Text = (dt.Rows[1][5] as IFormattable)
   ?.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

**Edit:** Where time part comes from.

When we put

```
 TB_Birthday.Text = dt.Rows[1][5].ToString();
```

we read `dt.Rows[1][5]` which is boxed `DateTime`. `DateTime` structure has  `Date` and `Time` parts. In your case `Time` part is *all zeroes*. However when you format with a help of `.ToString()` default format will be used which in your case includes `Time` part. So you have

```
 12:00:00 9/14/2019
```

All zeroes time is midnight (`12:00:00` in 12 hour format)

Comment: thanks `?.ToString()` causing error say  Syntax error, ':' expected please Dmitry update your answer with the explanation of from where time comes ... thnaks

Comment: @sam: if you work with some old version of C# you can put it as `.ToString()`, not to `?.ToString()` providing `dt.Rows[1][5] != null`

Comment: I am using .net4 with vs 2013

Comment: without `?.Tostring` I got No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: `TB_Birthday.Text = (dt.Rows[1][5] as IFormattable).ToString("M/d/yyyy");` do not forget `as IFormattable` - true, `object` doesn't have `ToString(string fromat)` method

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo: `(dt.Rows[1][5] as IFormattable).ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`

Comment: @sam: You are welcome! Next time, please, put a tag with compiler version (like .net-4.0)